# Is it possible to pass a table as a parameter to a user-defined function in SQL ADW that will be queried inside the function?

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I am writing a CREATE TABLE script for Azure Data Warehouse that will be recreating schema of a partitioned table. My script has repetitive code that queries a table and creates a comma separated string from column values. I am trying to move this repetitive code into a separate function so that it can be reused.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCreateStringFromColValues] (
    @tblName [NVARCHAR](255)
    , @colName [NVARCHAR](255) 
    , @RNumColName [NVARCHAR](255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @nRows INT = (SELECT count(*) FROM @tblName)
    DECLARE @count INT = 1
    DECLARE @toReturn AS nvarchar(MAX) = ''

    WHILE (@count <= @nRows)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @column varchar(200) = (SELECT @colName FROM @tblName WHERE @RNumColName = @count1)
        SET @toReturn = @toReturn + @column + ','
        SET @count = @count + 1
    END
    RETURN @toReturn
END
```

After searching through the web I am still not sure how user-defined functions work and if what I want to do can be achieved. Can the @tblName be passed dynamically and can I query the passed table inside my function? Right now, I get the following error while trying to create this function 
"Parse error at line: 16, column: 45: Incorrect syntax near '@tblName'. "

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support table-valued parameters but as at July 2019 it does support the powerful string manipulation functions `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_SPLIT`.  So there is no need to create a user-defined function, simply use the built-in ones.

A simple example that works in Azure SQL Data Warehouse as at today:

```
SELECT object_id, STRING_AGG( name, ', ' ) colList
FROM sys.columns
GROUP BY object_id
```